# How to integrate .Net unit tests with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

Earlier I was using `Visual Studio Load Test` to generate load for my load testing. I created .Net unit tests which I called by VS Load Test. Now VS Load Test is retired by Microsoft. Can I integrate my existing .Net code with JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot integrate .NET code with JMeter because as per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/)

> The Apache JMeter™ application is open source software, a **100% pure Java application** designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance. It was originally designed for testing Web Applications but has since expanded to other test functions.

If you still can execute your Web Tests, you can replay them via JMeter's proxy.

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The easiest way is going for [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature/)

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording" and click "Create"

     [image]
   - Open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"

     [image]
2. Prepare Visual Studio for Recording, in your [Web Test Project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUQRh.png) set JMeter as the proxy:

   [image]
3. Run your Visual Studio test
4. JMeter will capture the requests and create the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

You might need to still perform [correlation/parameterization](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) manually.

Comment: We are using Visual Studio Test to generate load. There are no HTTP calls. Test just sends data via Visual Studio Load Test.